# Cloudformation template to attach existing policy to existing IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to attach an aws managed policy to an existing role. I am achieving this using template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation template to modify Role",
    "Parameters": {
        "MyRole": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "MyRole",
            "Description": "Role to be modified"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "S3FullAccess": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [{
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:*",
                            "s3-object-lambda:*"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "*"
                    }]
                },
                "Roles": [
                    "MyRole"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This template will create a policy with s3FullAccess and attach it to MyRole. But I do not want to create a new policy, if I want to use the policy already present with aws for s3 full access, how can I do that.

And if I use this template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation template to modify Role",
    "Resources": {
        "IAMRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
                ],
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [{
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "*"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                "RoleName": "RoleName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will attempt to create a new role and attach ReadOnlyPolicy to it. But if I want to attach a policy to existing role, how to refer that role in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You use your `AWS::IAM::Role`'s [ManagedPolicyArns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-managepolicyarns) property, where you just specify the ARN of the  manage policy to attach.

To use existing role in CloudFormation, you have to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) it. Then you will be able to manage it from CloudFormation.

Comment: If I use, AWS::IAM::Role, there is no way to specify the existing role. It attempts to create a new role and then attach the policy with ManagedPolicyArns to newly created role.

Comment: @PRaw You add existing managed policy to the role in your template, using `ManagedPolicyArns` property.

Comment: right,  I tried that, but how to refer existing role in it.

Comment: @PRaw I'm not sure what do you mean. Maybe it would be good idea to make new question, specific to the role issue with the CFN template that you use. Your current question is about policy, and does not present any roles in it.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please Check if you can help. @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

In general, CloudFormation service is for creating resources. There is not a native support to do something with already created resources if you don't import them.

If you don't want to import them, then, you have an option to write CloudFormation custom resource.  You can create a lambda function-backed custom resource passing in the ARNs of the IAM policy  and the IAM role you want to attach the policy to by IAM `AttachRolePolicy` API. More details are in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).